# GCC C++ bug? (T)x matching X::operator const T&() const differs from clang's

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, language-lawyer, conversion-operator

I've encountered a discrepancy between GCC and clang (big range of versions thereof tested at godbolt - all had same discrepancy) with conversion operator matching.  Now using Barry's shorter reproduction code - also available at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/giDKSP).

```
struct X {
    template <typename T>
    operator T const&() const;
};

int i = X();
```

Should `operator T const&() const` match when converting to `int` (clang says yes / GCC needs `operator T() const` to avoid:

```
<source>:6:9: error: cannot convert 'X' to 'int' in initialization
        6 | int i = X();
          |         ^~~
```

The relevant part of the C++17 Standard is **15.3 Conversions [class.conv]**.  Therein, 15.3.5 says...

> Function overload resolution (16.3.3) selects the best conversion function to perform the conversion.

...which is almost what's important.  16.3.3 is the section for **Best viable function [over.match.best]**, but usually works in combination **16.3.2 viable functions [over.match.viable]**.  The Standard doesn't seem explicit about whether 16.3.2 applies here, but assuming it does, we have in 16.3.2.1:

> From the set of candidate functions constructed for a given context (16.3.1), a set of viable functions is chosen

Which raises the question of whether GCC considers `operator const T&() const` a candidate that's not viable, or not even a candidate.  The requirements for a candidate to be valid are very simple though: right number of arguments, and that *"there shall exist for each argument an implicit conversion sequence (16.3.3.1) that converts that argument to the corresponding parameter..."*, which is obviously true here, so I believe GCC must not consider `operator const T&() const` a candidate, which takes us to **16.3.1 Candidate functions and argument lists [over.match.funcs]**, and specifically 16.3.1/7:

> In each case where a candidate is a function template, candidate function template specializations are
>   generated using template argument deduction (17.8.3, 17.8.2). Those candidates are then handled as
>   candidate functions in the usual way.

Given say `template <typename T> void f(const T&);` could be called with an `int` argument type, I'd think GCC should have considered the conversion operator a valid candidate, just like clang does.

I'd appreciate confirmation / thoughts though.  If folks are in agreement, I'll raise a bug report against GCC.

Comment: Much shorter reproduction for your question: https://godbolt.org/z/giDKSP

Comment: For what it's worth, MSVC also compiles.

Comment: The rules around here are pretty fuzzy and I'm not sure we even know what we want them to say.

Comment: @Barry: yeah - I wouldn't complain about either choice (it's nice to be able to specify different behaviours for by-value and by-ref conversions, but probably rarely used), but it's rough when compilers make different choices!  (+thanks for the shorter repro)

Comment: @eerorika: thanks for the extra data point; I'll mention that if I raise this with the GCC folks

Comment: @Barry: There is a "new" conformance view in godbolt [Demo with one operator](https://godbolt.org/z/tBQ-PT) [Demo with both operators](https://godbolt.org/z/82XNAE).

Comment: @Jarod42 Not that new, been there for quite some time :-)

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63217

Comment: @T.C. Thanks!  So much for that then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a GCC bug as [pointed out by T.C.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63217).